# Выводить изменившуюся переменную

Tags: php

Здравствуйте даже не знал какой запрос вбивать в поисковик вот и решил спросить здесь
Имеется переменная

```
$p = 'текст';
echo $p;
$p = 'новый текст';
```

Хочу чтобы выводилось на экран слово **новый текст** то есть даже если после вывода переменная где-то изменяется то выводился последний результат можно ли такое реализовать, большое спасибо

Comment: Не имеете ли вы ввиду, что переменную надо выводить при каждом изменении?

Потому что изменить вывод, когда он уже на экране - это только под кокаином можно придумать.

Comment: Шадоу я просто нахожусь в состоянии ни смеха, ни плача, я просто горд за то что некоторые тут пишут!
>это только под кокаином можно придумать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересная задачка ))) 
Но если я правильно ее понял то конечно решаема, вот примерно накропал вариант решения (За неказистый код прошу не пинать, писал наспех левой пяткой ;))

Идея, я думаю, ясна из кода ниже, но на всякий случай поясню.
Там где нам требуется "отложенный" echo вместо него используем метод show класса WAIT_ECHO класс вместо содержимого переменной $p ставит свою метку и привязывает к ней ссылку на переменную. Ну и в самом конце, автоматически сработает функция класса __destruct которая подменит метки класса на актуальное содержимое переменных

Класс:

```
<?php
// Файл: wait_echo.php
Class WAIT_ECHO {
    private $vars = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        ob_start();
    }

    public function show(&$var)
    {
        $key = 'WAIT_ECHO_'.microtime();
        $this->vars[$key] = &$var;
        echo $key;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        foreach($this->vars as $key => $value)
        {
            $content = str_replace($key, $value, $content);
        }
        echo $content;
    }
}
?>
```

И теперь использование класса:

```
<?php
include 'wait_echo.php'; // Обязательно в первой строчке!!!

$wait = new WAIT_ECHO;
$p = 'текст';
$wait->show($p);
$p = 'новый текст';
?>
```

Comment: Деструктор не обязан вызываться в самом конце. Более того, он вообще может быть не вызван. Если уж очень хочется лапшакода, то лучше через echo выводить placeholder'ы, а в ob handler'е заменять их на реальные переменные.

Answer (score 1):

Нет нельзя.

```
$p = 'текст';
echo $p;
$p = 'новый текст';
```

Это php и раз выводим сначала переменную, а потом присваиваем ей новое значение, то выводить придется заново.

Вопрос, зачем выводить данные, если переменная еще миллион раз поменяться может? Выведи нужный результат в конце!

Comment: ну в конце то вывести это понятно а если нужно будет вывести в начале, ну раз не возможно то не возможно но если честно не думаю что  не реально реализовать такое

Comment: Лисапед)

    $t = 'Текст';
    unset($t);
    if(!isset($t))
    {
        $t = 'Новый текст';
    }
    echo $t;

Катайтесь)

Comment: @Palmervan Но вывод то в конце! 

А человеку нужно не в конце, а в середине :)

Comment: ну тогда не судьба)

Answer (score 0):

Заведите вторую переменную, и сделайте условие:

```
Если (Переменная1 не равна Переменная2) То
Вывести: Переменная1
Переменная2:=Переменная1
Конец Условия
```

Извините за псевдокод, PHP не знаю

Comment: ну это не совсем то что я имел в виду

Comment: А как тогда??, уточните вопрос...

Comment: ну переменная может изменяться не один раз и делать столько проверок думаю не лучший способ

Comment: @royal, вы не пробовали сказать то, о чем подумаете через 15 мин? Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, вам просто нужно научится [разделять данные от их представления](https://www.google.ru/search?q=разделение+логики+от+представления), например, при помощи какого-либо [шаблонизатора](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80). Т.е. ваш код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
// шаблон
$tpl = <<< EOF
...
{p} <!-- это переменная $p -->
...
EOF;

// основная логика
$p = 'текст';
// some do
$p = 'новый текст';

// the end
render($tpl, array('p' => $p));
```

**UPD.**

Вариант "в лоб". Так, как хочет ТС:

```
<?php
ob_start('LazyVar::obHandler');

$p = new LazyVar('текст');
echo $p;
$p->set('новый текст');
```

Где LazyVar:

```
class LazyVar {
    private $value;
    static private $collection = new SplObjectStorage();

    static public function obHandler($buffer) {
        foreach (self::$collection as $var) {
            $buffer = str_replace($var, (string)$var->get(), $buffer);
        }
        return $buffer;
    }

    public function __constructor($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
        self::$collection->attach($this);
    }

    public function set($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "<!-- ".spl_object_hash($this)." -->";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну это в идеале, на практике частенько бывает, что приходишь когда все возможные глупости уже сделаны и тебе не остается ничего кроме как придумывать свои "велосипеды", чтобы все написанное до тебя хоть как-то могло выполнять новые задачи. Ну или переписывать все с ноля, на что редко какой заказчик согласится.

Кстати отсутствием четкого разделения логики грешат даже некоторые популярные цмс. Типичный пример Битрикс, но у них тоже есть свой "велосипед" отложенные функции, так вроде называется.

Comment: проще уже было просто echo в конец скрипта переставить :)

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что речь идет о возможности обновить данные без перезагрузки страницы. В чистом виде на PHP не решается, а вот если добавить тот же jQuery - то вполне. Копать можно отсюда:

1. [jQuery и ajax для начинающих](http://anton.shevchuk.name/javascript/jquery-for-beginners-ajax/)
2. [Документация на сайте jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт выполняется построчно, т.е. тогда когда выполнится вверху echo остаток кода еще не будет прочитан интерпритатором по этой простой причине в том виде, в котором поставлена задача выполнить ее нельзя.